# aspect opinion mapping in product reviews

Tags: python, nltk

I have reviews of amazon products and am trying out to figure out a way of extracting nearby opinions from the aspect occurred in the review. i am using nltk package to do preprocessing.One of the ideas is to have two lists one having the features and other having the corresponding opinions. i am figuring a way to map these two so that correct feature opinion pair come to existence.

Eg: Samsung has low speakers and small,average screen.

aspect = ['speakers','screen']
opinion = ['low','small','average']

now how to get the mapping as 'low-speakers' , 'small-average-screen'

thinking on the terms of multiplying between 2 lists based on a range value

Could anyone help me figure this out?